# Typescript linting in Sublimetext doesn't work after updating Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I updated the node packages of my Angular 4 project with 
`npm install`.

For whatever strange reason the TypeScript linter in my Sublime Text Editor is now not working any more - it's not highlighting undefined variables etc.

If I open files from another Angular project, the linter works as expected though.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-sassy-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.8",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-chips": "^1.6.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "tldjs": "^2.3.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.102",
    "codelyzer": "^4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Dear downvoter, maybe you want to elaborate on how to improve this question?

Comment: Can you rule out that this was caused by the recent SublimeLinter 4 update?

Comment: I believe so, because when I opened files from another Angular project it worked. Ng lint (Angular CLI) didn't work either. However, after restarting the the local server it worked again at some point. Just weird though, because it was not the first restart. So my problem is solved (at least right now), but I don't know why and hence can't answer my own question.